# Image missing tiles and svg

Tags: css, svg, leaflet, html2canvas

I am using Html2Canvas and leaflet.  When I pan the map left, right, up, or down and then export I get a image in which I am missing tiles.  Also my overlay is no longer there. But if I don't pan I get my overlay.  Here is a picture of the missing tiles. [image]

Does any one know how to correct this?

Here is my code

```
//CSS
/* Map */
 #map {
    height: 440px;
}
//HTML 
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="exportDiv">
    <button id="btnClickHere" type="button">Click Me!</button>
</div>
//Javascript
      var tilesReady;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        buildMap();

        $("#btnClickHere").on("click", function () {
           exportMap();
        });
    });
    function exportMap() {
        //get transform value
        html2canvas($("#map")[0], {
            useCORS: true,
            background: "#E8F0F6",
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                var a = document.createElement('a');
                a.download = name;
                a.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.click();
            },
            width: 800,
            height: 500
        });
    }
    function buildMap() {
        tilesReady = false;
        map = L.map('map', {
            center: [28.418749, -81.581211],
            zoom: 12
        });
        var data = [{
            "coords": [28.3710, -81.5500],
                "time": 1
        }, {
            "coords": [28.4186, -81.5811],
                "time": 2
        }, {
            "coords": [28.3570, -81.5561],
                "time": 3
        }];
        var layers =    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: "Map: Tiles Courtesy of MapQuest (OpenStreetMap, CC-BY-SA)",
            subdomains: ["otile1", "otile2", "otile3", "otile4"],
            maxZoom: 18,
            minZoom: 2
        }).addTo(map);
        /* Initialize the SVG layer */
        map._initPathRoot();
        /* We simply pick up the SVG from the map object */
        var svg = d3.select("#map").select("svg"),
            g = svg.append("g");
        /* Add a LatLng object to each item in the dataset */
        data.forEach(function (d) {
            d.LatLng = new L.LatLng(d.coords[0],
            d.coords[1]);
        });
        var feature = g.selectAll("circle")
            .data(data)
            .enter().append("circle")
            .style("stroke", "black")
            .style("opacity", '.6')
            .style("fill", "red")
            .attr("r", 20);
        map.on("viewreset", update);
        update();
     function update() {
            feature.attr("transform",
            function (d) {
                return "translate(" + map.latLngToLayerPoint(d.LatLng).x + "," + map.latLngToLayerPoint(d.LatLng).y + ")";
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: We'd need to see your code to have a chance at answering this.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the code in there, and I don't mean just a link, the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to wait until all your tiles load on your tile layer before you begin the capture process. See

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-load

Attach the event with layer.on('load', callback)

Comment: I added that code in the fiddle but still I am getting the missing tiles.  I have updated the fiddle version with the code in it https://jsfiddle.net/japiasente/7ybndo5L/

Comment: Okay, so my initial answer is not going to helping you as I read this code more. When I produce a screenshot, I get a image with extra space on the bottom and some of your overlay circles cut off. I am in chrome for mac. What browser are you experiencing problems in?

Comment: Using Chrome gives me the missing tiles, When using firefox I get the tiles but I lose the svg overlay.  On IE it wont export due to me calling toDataURL.